# What am I missing with this code? Google foo.bar

Tags: java

So recently I got invited to this google foo.bar challenge and I believe the code runs the way it should be. To be precise what I need to find is the number of occurrences of "abc" in a String. When I verify my code with them, I pass 3/10 test cases. I'm starting to feel bad because I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have written the code which I will share with you guys. Also the string needs to be less than 200 characters. When I run this from their website, I pass 3 tests and fail 7. Basically 7 things need to be right.

The actual question: 
Write a function called answer(s) that, given a non-empty string less
than 200 characters in length describing the sequence of M&Ms. returns the maximum number of equal parts that can be cut from the cake without leaving any leftovers.

Example : Input : (string) s = "abccbaabccba"

output : (int) 2

Input: (string) s = "abcabcabcabc"

output : (int) 4

```
public static int answer(String s) { 

 int counter = 0;       
 int index;

 String findWord ="ABC";
    if(s!=null && s.length()<200){
     s = s.toUpperCase();

    while (s.contains(findWord))
    {
        index = s.indexOf(findWord);
        s = s.substring(index + findWord.length(), s.length());
        counter++;
    }

    }


  return counter;

 }
```

Comment: `if (s.length() < 200) { ...` - and if the search-text is longer than 200 character? This by the way is a well-know porblem (exact text search), maybe you want to read up on it since O(n) solutions exists. like the [KMP-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [BM-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Comment: Can you add the tests ?

Comment: What exactly is your task?

Comment: My task is to find the number of abc from the given String. An an example if user inputs "abccbaabccba" I have to output the number 2. I also can't add the test because I don't know what it is. It's not given. @Turing85 what you mentioned is also something I can't figure out. I as well can't understand what happens if character is more than 200.

Comment: @ArminAlipour then... write your own test(s) or try to debug. We will not do this for you.

Comment: @ArminAlipour If the word is more than 200 Characters long, the while loop will be skipped, meaning that the counter has been set to 0 and the function will return zero. On the other hand, if the string 's' has the value NULL (no value) it will break. So replace the if statement with: if(s!=null && s.length()<200)

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you @Flying Dutch Boy.

Comment: @FlyingDutchBoy not necessarily. It depends on the contract. It may be preferable to throw an exception if you pass in `null` (as opposed to "") instead of returning an incorrect result. This is what many methods in the Java API will also do.

Comment: @ArminAlipour you've just edited your solution in an attempt to make it case-insensitive. Is that one of the requirements? If so, you shouldn't do case-insensitive compares by converting to uppercase (or lowercase). There are some locale-related issues that will cause such comparisons to produce incorrect results. You should instead use API methods for ignoring case.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou If convert the main String into uppercase it should get rid of upper and lower case issue. Wouldn't???

Comment: @ArminAlipour not always. In some European languages, certain small letters with accents lose their accents when capitalised. So multiple lower-case letters can map to the same upper-case letter. Read more about it at https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding

Comment: @ArminAlipour since it's still failing 7 of the tests, give us the _exact_ words of the task specification. Maybe there's something you missed in there.

Comment: You misunderstood the requirement. M&M colors can be anything from a to z, not necessarily in alphabetical order

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things in your code snippet:

1.

`if(s.length()<200){`

Why are you checking for the length to be lesser than 200? Is that a requirement? If not, you can skip checking the length.

2.

```
String findWord ="abc";
...
s.contains(findWord)
```

Can the test program be checking for upper case alphabets? Example: "ABC"? If so, you might need to consider changing your logic for the `s.contains()` line.

> Update:

You should also consider putting a `null` check for the input string. This will ensure that the test cases will not fail for `null` inputs.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention it. Yes it's required to have less than 200 characters. I will make a change for uppercase letters as you mentioned so I can see if at least I pass 1 more test.

Comment: @anacron Don't forget the nullcheck. If string s is NULL the if statement in 1. will definitly break So that should be: if(s!=null && s.length()<200){

Comment: @FlyingDutchBoy, You're absolutely right.. That's a good catch.. I'll update that too in my answer.. Thanks..

Comment: I tried "ABC" I still got the same result. Failing 7 tests. I thought if a program runs and satisfies the requirement it's good enough. But after this, it completely killed my hope.

Comment: @ArminAlipour before searching through the string do s = s.toUpperCase(); findWord = findWord.toUpperCase(); It will turn everything into upper case, meaning that case wont matter anymore.

Comment: I changed it, is that what you mean?

Comment: @ArminAlipour Not exactly, now " s = s.toUpperCase();" can be executed before the if statement, meaning you can get a null pointer, move  s = s.toUpperCase(); to the first rule after the if statement

Comment: I am missing the small details. Interesting facts... I believe this should be what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is well but on the other hand i found that you didn't check for if input string is empty or null. 
I belief that google foo.bar wants to see the logic and the way of coding in a proper manner.

so don't be feel bad

Comment: true!!! I tried fixing the top if statement before sharing it here but since I failed 7 tests I forgot about doing more research about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a simpler approach

```
int beforeLen = s.length ();
String after = s.replace (findWord, "");
int afterLen = after.length ();

return (beforeLen - afterLen) / findWord.length ();
```

Answer (score 0):

put declaration of index out before while block, isn't never good re-declare the same variable n time.

```
    int index;
    while (s.contains(findWord))
    {
        index = s.indexOf(findWord);
        ....
    }
```

I hope this help

> Update:

try to compact your code

```
public static int answer(String s) {

    int counter = 0;
    int index;

    String findWord = "ABC";
    if (s != null && s.length() < 200) {
        s = s.toUpperCase();

        while ((index = s.indexOf(findWord)) > -1) {
            s = s.substring(index + findWord.length(), s.length());
            counter++;
        }

    }

    return counter;

}
```

> Update:

The logic seems good to me, I'm still try to improve the performance, if you can try this

```
while ((index = s.indexOf(findWord, index)) > -1) {
     //s = s.substring(index + findWord.length(), s.length());
    index+=findWord.length();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Since index is a local variable and it's not being used outside I doubt it will make any trouble. I still changed it because it would be cleaner. Tnx for helping out.

Comment: hahah I can't say sure cause the second I say it, people will destroy me by proving me wrong... :))

Comment: Sorry update my answer, it's possible is a performance issue?

Comment: 7 fails still exists... :(

Comment: :( you try to add in if statement the condition  !s.isEmpty() after not null  condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "abc";
    String line="<input text here>";
    int i=0;
    Pattern TokenPattern=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    if(line!=null){
    Matcher m=TokenPattern.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()){
        i++;
    }}
    System.out.println("No of occurences : "+ " "+i);
```

Comment: use the import java.util.regex.* library